# why is []+[] equal to an empty string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is []+[] (two arrays) equal to an empty string in javascript? Furthermore, why does []+{} (array plus an object) equal an object and {}+[]=0?

Comment: [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: `[] + {}` is not an object, and `{} + []` is not zero. If you type it in a REPL, `{}` might be interpreted as an empty block, but it is impossible to encounter this in an actual script. `{} + []` and `[] + {}` both have the same result; both convert `[]` to an empty string and `{}` to `'[object Object]'`, and concatenate the two. `[]` is converted to an empty string in `[] + []` as well. This, in turn, is because `array.toString() === array.join(',')` for any array.

Comment: Essentially, “wat” doesn’t say anything useful about JavaScript. It’s just average comedy.

Comment: @Ryan: `[] + {}` and `{} + []` are different. Only in the second case `{}` will be interpreted as a block. In the first it's an object literal. Otherwise I agree :)

Comment: @FelixKling: The expressions `[] + {}` and `{} + []` have the same result. `{} + []` in a given REPL may or may not be an expression. Again, in an actual script, you can’t observe the result of block `{}`, statement `+[]` except in contrived `eval` situations.

Comment: @Ryan: In a REPL. But not in an actual program. A leading `{}` will always be interpreted as a block. The spec says so: [Expression statements cannot start with `{`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-expression-statement). *"you can’t observe the result of block `{}`, statement `+[]`"* That's right, but that doesn't mean that it's not happening ;)

Comment: @Ryan I'd stipulate that `[] + {}` and `({} + [])` have the same result, since in that case you're coercing the operation into an expression rather than a statement, otherwise saying they're the same is as Felix points out.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I said exactly what I meant to say. You’re never going to put `{} + []` in a script and get zero.